# How to check international academic credentials/degrees?

Tags: credentials

What is the most efficient way of checking the academic degrees of an international pool of job-seekers? The tough thing is that many graduated from institution of non-English speaking countries.

Comment: What do you want to check, if the person really has the degree (s)he says (s)he has, or the "quality" or level of the degree?

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens: the first.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of checks that can be done.

1. You can ask for a copy of their degrees but for added comfort you can ensure that they get a third party to certify them. For example I know in Ireland you can get a lawyer to view the original of a document, they photocopy it and certify that it is a true copy.
2. You could ask the graduation department of their university to confirm that they graduated with their degree.
3. In cases where the certificates are in a foreign language you could have a pre-approved translation service that the applicants have to use to translate any documents. Again for example (in a different field) when my brother and his wife emigrated to a country in the UAE the immigration office would only accept their official documents if they had being translated by a certain translation service provider.